# Proptypes validation for a react component constructor function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

If I want to ensure that a constructor function for a react component is passed in as a prop, how might I go about validating this using the PropTypes module?

For instance:

```
// Child Components
class MyComponent extends React.Component {}
const MyComponent2 = (props) => null; // stateless react component

// Container
class Container extends React.Component {}
Container.propTypes = { child: /*validator*/ }

// creating container class with MyComponent
<Container child={MyComponent}/> // validation succeeds

// creating container class with MyComponent2
<Container child={MyComponent2}/> // validation succeeds

// creating container class with random function
const func = function add(x,y) { return x+y; }
<Container child={func}/> // validation fails
```

Is something like this even possible, given that stateless components are simply functions with no explicit link to `React.Component`?

**Note:** I'm not looking to pass a react component into `Container` (as can be validated with `PropTypes.element`). I'm looking to pass the constructor for such a component.

Answer (score 0):

As per **[DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)**:

> Any function is a valid React component when they accepts a single
>   “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and
>   returns a **React element**. We call such components “functional”
>   because they are literally JavaScript functions.

But in your case, function is not returning the React element, its returning sum of two numbers.

One way to solve the issue is: wrap the `(x+y)` by `p` tag, like this:

```
const func = function add(x,y) { return <p>{ x+y }</p>; }
```

---

See Fundamentally, [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) is syntactic sugar for:

`React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`.

So when we write [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), its  gets complied to `React.createElement`.

**Update:**

You can use `child: PropTypes.element`, for `Proptypes` validation for React element. If child get any value other than a react element it will throw a warning.

```
Container.propTypes = {
   child: PropTypes.element
}
```

Comment: What I was getting at is that the add() function, not being a true stateless react component, should fail propType validation in the `Container` component while my two react components shouldn't. This is what I'm trying to achieve. I'll clear that up in the question

Comment: ohh, ok got the idea, check the update section. I think that will solve the issue. Let me know if that fails to solve your issue :)

Comment: I believe `PropTypes.element` only validates a pre-constructed react component (e,g `<List/>`). What I'm trying to achieve is to pass the constructor function for such a react component which the container can then use to construct that element. As you can see in my code example, I don't create an instance of `MyComponent`. I simply pass the constructor in as a prop instead